# Stop propogation of event listener click but still allow other click events to occur within the element

Tags: javascript, stoppropagation

I have created a fairly classic modal. Fixed modal in the middle of the screen. Semi-transparent background and a box in the middle.

The box contains some click event listeners (e.g a close X and a button that performs another action).

I want to allow the user to close the modal by clicking on the *outer* background.

## HTML example

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal__inner">
        <div class="modal_closebtn">X</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, I have the following to handle closing the modal based on click of `.modal`, which covers the whole screen.

```
document.querySelector(".modal").addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.toggleModal();
});
```

My problem is, this fires if you click inside the `.modal__inner` too.

So I tried adding an eventListener to `stopPropagation()`

```
document.querySelector(".modal__inner").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This now blocks the eventListener for my `.modal_closebtn` and any other events that occur inside the modal.

How can I ensure that the click for the background div only works on the `modal` div not `modal__inner` or any others? Unfortunately when I review `e.currentTarget` after clicking inside my div it returns `.modal` not `.modal__inner` even though it does appear that I clicked inside that div.

**Non jQuery solution please**

Comment: What if you got rid of the nesting and made the box a sibling of the background cover?  Could add a new parent if you need it.

Comment: what about pushing the modal one z-index up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the execution of `querySelector` too many times and gain a little of performance, store that result into a variable.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".modal")
elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target !== elem) return;
  console.log('toggle!');
  //this.toggleModal();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 300px
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000
}

.modal__inner {
  width: 100px
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div id="hola" class="modal">
  Parent modal
  <br>
  <br>
 
  <br>
  <div id="epale" class="modal__inner">
    Inner modal
    <div class="modal_closebtn">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Happy coding!**

Answer (score 2):

The event object has the original [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) of the event, use that to figure out what is the source of the event.

```js
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
modal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target !== modal) return;
    this.toggleModal();
});
```

Comment: Ah perfect thank you! I was looking at `e.currentTarget` not `target`